# How the Life Drain effect calculates if I fail CON save?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

My character was hit by a Wraith's Life Drain, and it was a critical hit. My HP was at 29/33, and I took 32 necrotic damage.

**How order of the max HP reduction should be calculated?**

> My interpretation:
>
> 1. 29/33 HP
> 2. Takes 32 necrotic dmg, fail CON save
> 3. -3/1 HP
> 4. Dies

---

> My DM interpretation
>
> 1. 29/33 HP
> 2. Takes 32 necrotic dmg, fail CON save
> 3. -3/33 HP, die? No.
> 4. 0/1 HP, unconscious.

Which interpretation is right?